# ModuleNotFoundError for 'llama_index.vector_stores' in Python Project

Tags: large-language-model, llama-index

I'm working on a Python project involving embeddings and vector storage, and I'm trying to integrate llama_index for its vector storage capabilities with PostgreSQL. However, I'm encountering a ModuleNotFoundError when attempting to import PGVectorStore from llama_index.vector_stores. Here's the snippet of code that's causing the issue:

```
from llama_index.llms.openai import OpenAI
from llama_index.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbedding
from llama_index.vector_stores.postgres import PGVectorStore

nest_asyncio.apply()
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.vector_stores'
```

What I've tried:

- Reinstalling the llama_index package to ensure it's up to date.
- Searching for similar issues online, but haven't found anything specific to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks the bug is resolved.

I needed to install pip install `llama-index-vector-stores-postgres`

For some reason it is not installing with `pip install llama-index`.